# How can I prove this relation between primes and congruences?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $p$ is a prime, and $a\equiv b(\bmod~p)$. Prove that

$$a^p\equiv b^p(\bmod~p^2)$$

So, from the first statement, we know that $p|(a-b)$ and that $[a]_p = [b]_p$. Bringing this over to the second statement, we have $p^2|(a^p-b^p)$ and $[a^p]_p=[b^p]_p$. I am not sure how to bridge these two congruence relations. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  Use the binomial theorem: since $a=b+kp$ we have
$$a^p=(b+kp)^p=b^p+\cdots\ ,$$
and with a bit of thought you will be able to see why all the remaining terms are divisible by $p^2$.

Comment: So upon expanding, I get something that looks like $b^p+{p\choose 1} b^{p-1}pk+{p\choose 2} b^{p-2}(pk)^2 + ... +{p\choose p} (pk)^p$ and upon bringing bp over to the left hand side, each term on the RHS has a $p^2$ in it therefore they are all divisible by p2 making the RHS divisible by $p^2$, therefore the LHS must also be divisible by $p^2$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.  Wouldn't even bother taking $b^p$ to the LHS, you have $a^p=b^p+Kp^2$ which answers the question.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Let us prove the statement not only for $p$ prime, but for all natural numbers $n$.
Indeed, $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\dots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$, $\forall a,b,n\in \mathbb{N}$, then since $n|(a-b)$, we only have to prove that $a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\dots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}\equiv 0$ (mod $n$).
We use again the fact that $a\equiv b$ (mod $n$), so that $\forall j=0,1,\dots,n-1$, we have $a^{n-1-j}b^j\equiv a^{n-1-j}a^j=a^{n-1}$ (mod $n$), a simple property of congruences, and so:
$a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\dots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}\equiv na^{n-1}=0$ (mod $n$).